# it shows 'Cannot connect: invalid settings.' and ' Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.' message. whats wrong with it?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I use Ubuntu 14.04 in my laptop. I am learning PHP and I am stuck here. I

I already tried to `purge` and reinstall phpmyadmin but it doesn't seem to work. Apache failed to run instead and showed

```
XAMPP: Starting Apache...fail.
XAMPP:  Another web server is already running.
```

By stopping `apache2` apache is still running but phpmyadmin still shows

```
access denied!
```

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Sounds like a conflict between XAMPP and the native LAMP components - do you really need XAMPP?

Comment: yea. coz now i'm learning php.

Comment: OK sure but you talk about 'purge' and 'reinstall' which sounds like you are referring to the native version of php from the Ubuntu repository - that's a separate route from using XAMPP

Comment: so what should i do ? do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
```

in terminal